# linux authentication window script

Tags: linux

i want to run some graphic application on linux startup also  it should start  just after authentication confirms. 
If any body having any idea then please reply very soon!!!

Platform linux-6
thank you

Comment: you mean centos 6.0 when you said linux-6

Answer (score 0):

if you meant centos 6  write your scripts to /etc/rc.local. rc.local will be executed after all init scripts.